# asp.net connecting to an external database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a an external database hosted by Strato and I would like to connect my asp.net c# to the external database and insert a new user in to the database but I got an error when I tried to established the connection. The error occured at con.open(); Can anyone help me with this? I am new to asp.net so any sample code may be helpful. For now I am just trying to establish a connection to the database and transfer a static data to the table upon clicking the submit button.

web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices"
connectionString="server=rdbms.strato.de;database=DB33321; UID=abc123; password=pass123"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into USER"+"(name)values(kim)");

    Response.Write("Registration success!");
    con.Close();
}
```

The error i received:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Looking at Strato website it looks like they only have MySql databases. Is that correct? If so you are using the wrong provider. Use `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand`, etc.

Comment: Can you please further elaborate? Strato indeed only have MySql database, does that mean I can't connect it via asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

You probably found examples of connecting to a database without realizing there are several providers for ADO.Net. For MySql you need a nuget package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/

You will then change your connection string so the Provider is not `System.Data.SqlClient`. I believe it should be `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`

Next you change your code so that it uses the correct Types. Wherever you see "Sql..." you change it to "MySql...". for instance:

`SqlConnection` becomes `MySqlConnection`.

Comment: I still encountered the same problem despite all the changes. Is possible that the provider (strato) does not support this? Since their website only shows how to connect with php codes.

Comment: I expect it to work with .Net but there may be firewall issues or something else. Can you contact Strato support?

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. I will work out with strato and see how it goes.